# Refresh view page without reloading the page manually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to refresh view page without clicking on refresh button.

Javascript code:--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {     
        var metaId = $("#ID").val();
        var img = $("#@name input[type=hidden]").val();
        if ("@found" == "False") {
            $.post(rootURL + "Picture/AddThumb", { guidOrName: img, meta: metaId, id: contentId }, function (data) {
                //arrangePoster([data]);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Post sometimes doesn't work. 
It is better to use **ajax** jquery method. 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
Then on Picture/AddThumb add printing parameters. 
Use done to show data resulted ( to test also if it works correctly )